# Update Missing Data In Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a table with sample data set-up like below.  How can I update the missing data for the field `rglname`?  There will always only be **ONE** `rglname` assigned to `region` so I am not worried about duplicate values.  Below is DDL

```
Create Table #BlueBell
(
  ID int
  ,region varchar(100)
 ,rglname varchar(500)
)

Insert Into #BlueBell VALUES
(1, 'East', 'Bob')
,(2, 'East', NULL)
,(3, 'East', NULL)
,(4, 'West', 'Sam')
,(5, 'West', NULL)
,(6, 'South', NULL)
,(7, 'South', NULL)
,(8, 'South', NULL)
,(9, 'South', 'Mitch')
```

And desired output is:

> ID    Region  RGLName
>   1   East    Bob
>   2   East    Bob
>   3   East    Bob
>   4   West    Sam
>   5   West    Sam
>   6   South   Mitch
>   7   South   Mitch
>   8   South   Mitch
>   9   South   Mitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following update.

```
update #BlueBell set rglname = b.rglname
from #BlueBell a
inner join (
            select region, rglname
            from #BlueBell where rglname is not null
            ) b on a.region = b.region
```

Check your desired output here

```
select * 
from #BlueBell
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to copy the `RGLName` for a `Region` to the other rows with the same `Region` value that currently have a `NULL RGLName`?

If so, this will do it:

```
UPDATE 
    b
SET 
    b.rglname = bb.rglname
FROM 
    #BlueBell b 
JOIN
    #BlueBell bb 
on 
    b.region = bb.region
where 
    b.rglname IS NULL 
    and 
    bb.rglname IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM #BlueBells
+----+--------+---------+
| ID | region | rglname |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | East   | Bob     |
|  2 | East   | Bob     |
|  3 | East   | Bob     |
|  4 | West   | Sam     |
|  5 | West   | Sam     |
|  6 | South  | Mitch   |
|  7 | South  | Mitch   |
|  8 | South  | Mitch   |
|  9 | South  | Mitch   |
+----+--------+---------+
```